# How to trigger a function on route-change from a specific route?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have login component which has the following method:

```
  login() {
    this.$v.loginValidationGroup.$touch();
    if (this.$v.loginValidationGroup.$error) {
      return;
    }
    this.setLogsInfo();

    userService.login(this.email, this.password, this.twoFactorAuthCode, this.rememberMe, this.userOs, this.userIp, this.userAgent, this.browserName)
      .then(authenticationToken => {
        if(authenticationToken === "2FactorAuthRequired") {
          this.is2FAuthEnabled = true;
        }
        else {
          this.$store.dispatch('login', authenticationToken);
          this.$router.push('/Home');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error instanceof AuthenticationError && error.errorType === AuthErrorType.WRONG_CREDENTIALS) {
          this.loginError = 'wrongLoginCredentials';
        } else if (error instanceof ValidationError) {
          this.loginError = 'invalidLoginCredentials';
        } else {
          this.loginError = 'unknownLoginError';
        }
        this.$v.$reset();
      });
  },
```

After login the user is redirected to the Home component.

On my Home component I have made a modal that contains a welcome message:

```
   <template>
    <div class="modal v-model="visible">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Welcome</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            some text....
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </template>
```

Is there any way I can tell the application to set the v-model "visible" to true when routing from the Login component to the Home component?
Mind you I ONLY want the v-model be set to true when entering the page from the Login compoment,not any other component.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can make use of in-component navigation guard called "beforeRouteEnter". In it, you have access to the route which the router navigated from. You check if the `from` route is the login route, then set the `visible` variable through `vm` component instance provided by `next` function (remember in this navigation guard you don't have access to `this` component instance)

Home component:

```
  data(){
    return {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      if (from.path === "/login") {
        vm.visible = true;
      }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Home.vue` component, you can set a **router watcher**  which would have `to` and `from` params to check the `previous` and `current` routes.

Here is an example-

`Home.vue`

```
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    if(from.name == "Login") {
      this.visible = true;
    }
  }
}
```